# Python comparison of tuples inside a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples, iteration

I have this exercise that requires us to compare two lists of tuples.

The first list (`games`) has 3 tuples, each one corresponding to a game match, with the names of 2 people.

The second list (`results`) has also 3 tuples, each one corresponding to the results of each match (ordered with `games`).

```
games = [("anna", "ross"), ("manny", "maria"), ("rita", "joel")]
results = [(2, 0), (1, 3), (1, 1)]
```

The desired output is supposed to be this:

```
['anna', 'maria', 'TIE']
```

When both scores for a match are the same, the output `'TIE'`.

I tried to solve it with the `zip` function, but for some reason I can't iterate properly in all the levels of the tuples.

1st try:

```
lst = []
i = 0
for a, b in zip(games, results):
    if b[i] == max(b):
        lst.append(a[i])
    elif min(b) == max(b):
        lst.append("TIE")
i = i + 1
print(lst)
```

This returned `['anna', 'rita']`, which made me think there was some issue with iterating the list / tuples using `b[i]`.

Then I tried to do this:

```
lst = []
for i, c in list(zip(games, results)):
    for j, k in i, c:
        if k == max(c):
            lst.append(i[j])
        elif min(c) == max(c):
            lst.append('TIE')
print(lst)
```

This returned `['maria', 'TIE', 'joel']`, so I suppose the issue is not only with the iteration but maybe with the way that I'm making the comparison (using max function to find the highest score).

Can anyone give any tips or hints to help me move forward to the solution?
I'm asking only after spending a long time looking for a similar problem online and not being able to find anything that could really help.

Comment: How is `"anna"` and `"maria"` a tie when they didn't even play?

Comment: @ThePilotDude The tie is for the game between rita and joel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
games=[("anna","ross"),("manny","maria"),("rita","joel")]
results=[(2,0),(1,3),(1,1)]

def calculateResult(x,y):
    if(y[0]>y[1]):
        return x[0]
    elif(y[1]>y[0]):
        return x[1]
    else:
        return "TIE"

res = []
for i in range(len(games)):
    res.append(calculateResult(games[i],results[i]))
print(res)
```

Here, I pass individual tuples from both the lists, games and results into a function which compares the results and accordingly returns the output of the game.

Comment: Thanks!! That's a much simpler way to get the right output without having to use zip, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Inês Most Welcome! Please consider validating the answer as correct if you found this useful

Answer (score 1):

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is your friend here. Try:

```
games=[("anna","ross"),("manny","maria"),("rita","joel")]
results=[(2,0),(1,3),(1,1)]
final = []

for n, t in enumerate(results):
  if t[0] > t[1]:
    final.append(games[n][0])
  elif t[0] < t[1]:
    final.append(games[n][1])
  else:
    final.append("TIE")
```

---

```
['anna', 'maria', 'TIE']
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/66247f3e57)

Comment: `enumerate` is a *bad* "friend" here, `zip` is the right tool and the OP is already using it.

Comment: We don't need the indexes, only the value pairs. And that's precisely what `zip` does. I might even prefer `range` over `enumerate` here, that would at least be consistent, using indexes for both. Using indexes for one but not the other... that just feels weird.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also letting me know about ```enumerate``` ! (Comments below were also very informative)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
games=[("anna","ross"),("manny","maria"),("rita","joel")]
results=[(2,0),(1,3),(1,1)]
output = []
for g, r in zip(games, results):
    if r[0] == r[1]:
        output.append("TIE")
    elif r[0] < r[1]:
        output.append(g[1])
    else:
        output.append(g[0])
```

One of the problems in your second attempt is that k ==max() will return True, even if there is a tie. A tie just means both of the values in the tuple are the max since they are the same.

Comment: Thanks! :) Yes, that makes sense, like that I would never be able to make a distinction (which must have been the reason for the weird results).

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop is almost correct, but if you look at it carefully, `i = 0`, so you never append anything if the second person wins. You never loop over the case where `i = 1`.

Here is a clearer way of writing it:

```
lst = []
for names, scores in zip(games, results):
    if scores[0] > scores[1]:
        lst.append(names[0])
    elif scores[0] < scores[1]:
        lst.append(names[1])
    else:
        lst.append("TIE")
```

Given that you are always appending a simple element to a single list, you can rewrite this as a comprehension:

```
lst = [names[0] if scores[0] > scores[1] else names[1] if scores[0] < scores[1] else 'TIE' for names, scores in zip(games, results)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess the `i` was not of much use if we use `for`

Answer (score 0):

Just a list comprehension:

```
lst = [g1 if r1 > r2 else g2 if r2 > r1 else 'TIE'
       for (g1, g2), (r1, r2) in zip(games, results)]
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) that helped to understand a little better how to apply the zip function in this case.